# "Returning" values from XSLT stylesheet

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslcompiledtransform

I am using an `XSLTCompiledTransform` object as seen below to convert an XML report into an html report. I am using an `XsltArgumentList` to pass values from the C# code to the XSLT, but I also need to "return" values from the XSLT sheet to the C# code.

```
    XsltArgumentList argsList = new XsltArgumentList();
    argsList.AddParam("min_threshold", "", min_threshold);
    argsList.AddParam("max_threshold", "", max_threshold);
    argsList.AddParam("user", "", user);

    XslCompiledTransform writeHtml = new XslCompiledTransform(false);
    writeHtml.Load(userStyles);
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathHtml))
    {
    writeHtml.Transform(pathXml, argsList, sw);
    }
```

I have not been able to find anything documenting ways in which this can be done. I *could*  use LINQ to obtain the values I need directly from the `DataTable` from which the XML was written, but I would prefer to pull them from the XSL. It would be less code, and I would avoid having to compute the same value in two separate places.

Comment: Well, you can use extension objects https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-extension-objects and extension script to call .NET methods from inside your XSLT code. Does that help? There is no way to return anything other than the primary transformation result you currently have in your StreamWriter or you have in any type of result the Transform method allows as the last argument.

Comment: I think I will just go the LINQ route. If there is no simple way to do it from the XSL, the LINQ will really only be a few lines of code, and shouldn't impact performance. I was mostly hoping to save a few lines for readability / cleanliness if possible. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Although I have never done it what about xsl:message and use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltmessageencounteredeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx